# Could anyone please tell me why my code does not work in this code on symmetrical tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

I was doing this symmetrical tree problem on leetcode (the link to the problem : https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/), but could not find out why my code works when the binary tree looks like this :
[`root = [1,2,2,3,4,4,3]`][1]
but doesn't work when it's `root= [1,2,2]`
This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int n = 0;
static int left =0;
static int right = 0;
void symcenter(struct TreeNode* root1, struct TreeNode* root2){
    //base condition
    if((root1 == NULL) || (root2 == NULL) || (root1->val != root2->val)){
        return;
    }
    else{
        symcenter(root1->left, root2->right);
        n++;
        symcenter(root1->right, root2->left);
    }
}

//count the num of nodes
void countleft(struct TreeNode* root){
    if(root != NULL){
        countleft(root->left);
        left++;
        countleft(root->right);
    }
}

void countright(struct TreeNode* root){
    if(root != NULL){
        countright(root->right);
        right++;
        countright(root->left);
    }
}

bool isSymmetric(struct TreeNode* root){
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    countleft(root->left);
    countright(root->right);
    symcenter(root->left, root->right);
    if(left == right && n == left){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you for helping !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP1iX.png

Comment: Have you explained your code to [your rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/cyberduck/)?

Comment: You can laugh about someone not understanding in the meanwhile there are TRUE bots that develop software and they cost a M$.

Comment: Start by removing all global variables. Global variables are not your friends.

Comment: The title should be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Take a step back and look again at the problem. The root has 2 subtrees that must be identical for symmetrical traversals. You should traverse the left subtree in the following order: (Root, Left, Right) and the right subtree in the other order: (Root, Right, Left). Here is a simple solution in less than 10 lines of code

```
bool auxFunc(struct TreeNode *left, struct TreeNode *right) {
    if (right == NULL && left == NULL) return true;
    if (right == NULL || left == NULL) return false;
    return (right->val == left->val) && auxFunc(left->left, right->right) && auxFunc(left->right, right->left);
}

bool isSymmetric(struct TreeNode* root){
    return auxFunc(root->left, root->right);
}
```